# How to decode JSON that has multiple levels and store it's data?

Tags: json, swift, algorithm, api

I'm trying to code a mathematical algorithm to include in an app.

I am fetching the data from an API that returns many "levels", I need 14 of them. I also need to store each "level" values to use them (I also need to have them updated as often as possible but that would be for another thread I guess).

Here is how the beginning of the JSON looks like:

[image: JSON Sample Screenshot]

Link: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

Here is how I am trying to fetch the "0" level (Array?) data without success:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case data = "Data" }      
    let data : Data
}

struct Data : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case zero = "0" }
    let zero : Zero
}

struct Zero : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case time
        case open
        case high
        case low
        case close
    }
    let time : Double
    let open : Double
    let high : Double
    let low : Double
    let close : Double
}
```

and...

```
let marketData0 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

How can I fetch data from 0 to 13 "levels" and store them to use them in my calculations?

Comment: It's best to include an example of the JSON string when asking questions about parsing it. An image doesn't help as much as the actual string.

Comment: I added the JSON link is it okay?

Comment: In your link there is no actual "level" value. `Data` is simply a JSON array.

Comment: And each number is simply a case? How can I access each of them?